# @Autowired repositories are null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired

In my existing project (which features many similar endpoints, controllers and services), I added a new REST controller and service to create and save Entities of type `ExampleType` to the database. However, when I access a repository method inside the service, I get a `NullPointerException`:

**Stack Trace**

```
2020-05-31 18:21:49.584 ERROR 22460 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at myproject.service.exampletype.ExampleTypeServiceImpl.createExampleType(ExampleTypeServiceImpl.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at myproject.controller.exampletype.ExampleTypeController.createExampleType(ExampleTypeController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at myproject.controller.exampletype.ExampleTypeController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$23715a2e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at myproject.controller.exampletype.ExampleTypeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$863be5ca.createExampleType(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at myproject.security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at myproject.security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

**Code**

*ExampleTypeController*

```java
@RestController
public class ExampleTypeController extends ApiControllerV1 {
    private final ExampleTypeService exampleTypeService;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleTypeController(
            final ExampleTypeService exampleTypeService
    ) {
        this.exampleTypeService = exampleTypeService;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping("/exampleTypes")
    public ExampleType createExampleType(@RequestBody final ExampleTypeDto exampleTypeDto) {
        return exampleTypeService.createExampleType(exampleTypeDto);
    }
}
```

*ExampleTypeServiceImpl*

```java
@Service
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class ExampleTypeServiceImpl implements ExampleTypeService {
    private final ExampleTypeRepository exampleTypeRepository;
    private final BogusClassRepository bogusClassRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleTypeServiceImpl(
            final ExampleTypeRepository exampleTypeRepository,
            final BogusClassRepository bogusClassRepository
    ) {
        this.exampleTypeRepository = exampleTypeRepository;
        this.bogusClassRepository = bogusClassRepository;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public final ExampleType createExampleType(ExampleTypeDto exampleTypeDto) {
        ExampleType exampleType = new ExampleType();
        exampleType.setDescription(exampleTypeDto.getDescription());
        exampleType.setActive(true);
        Long bogusClassId = exampleTypeDto.getBogusClass();
        final BogusClass bogusClass = bogusClassRepository.findById(bogusClassId).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException());
        exampleType.setBogusClass(bogusClass);
        return exampleTypeRepository.save(exampleType);
    }
}
```

*ExampleTypeRepository*

```java
public interface ExampleTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ExampleType, Long> {
    Optional<ExampleType> findById(@NonNull Long id);
}
```

*BogusClassRepository*

```java
public interface BogusClassRepository extends JpaRepository<BogusClass, Long> {
    Optional<BogusClass> findById(@NonNull Long id);
}
```

**Notes + What I've tried so far:**

- The autowired repositories (`ExampleTypeRepository` and `BogusClassRepository` are also used in another service, where everything works as expected
- I already tried using the `@Repository` annotation on my repositories, which had no effect. Also, all other repositories in the project are working just fine without it.
- I tried to use field based DI instead of constructor based, which did not change anything.
- I tried to debug the autowiring process: The repositories are definitely autowired by the `ExampleTypeService` constructor on application start.
- I also checked that there are no instances of my controller, service or repositories created using the `new` keyword. From what I see, they are all autowired.
- The implementations shown here closely follow other (known working) implementations in the project controllers, services, and repositories.

Comment: Just a try - remove the final from the method. Could cause errors with spring proxies.

Comment: could add also the packages of the classes and the application class?

Comment: @TomStroemer removing the `final` from the `createExampleType` method in `ExampleClassServiceImpl` fixed it. I was about sure that I had tried every possible combination of final/non-final, but there it was, thank you!Could you submit this as an answer so that I could mark it as solving my question?

Edit: I have a method in another service where the `final` does not cause any problems whatsoever… Strange…